# Access Denied to server linux SSH

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, security, ssh-keys

I can't access the server using ssh user@IP with the right password i get access denied even though the sshd config is set correctly i restarted it reloaded nothing worked.
I generated an rsa key over one machine the only one that can access the server anny suggestions

Comment: run the client in verbose mode `ssh -vvvvv user@ip`

Comment: from the distant machine ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Problem Solved Reboot the Server and restart ssh services.

Answer (score 2):

Check /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the server, maybe there are some Match Address rule or your user is not allowed to login from ssh. Check messages with ssh -vv user@IP for some hint.
If you cannot reach the password prompt, check firewall rules.

Best regards